# t.test in R gives weird results when assigned to a list object

Tags: r, statistics

I define two clearly differing vectors:

```
> x1 = c(3, 4, 3, 4)
> x2 = c(9, 8, 9, 7)
```

If I perform a t-test using *t.test* without assigning it to an object name I get the expected result. As in:

```
> t.test(x1, x2)

# Gives the console output:

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -8.4971, df = 4.927, p-value = 0.000399
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.193426 -3.306574
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
     3.50      8.25
```

This gives a large t-value and small p-value suggesting that the two vectors have different means, as expected. However, if I assign a t-test to an object name to create a list object by:

```
mean.diff = mean(x1) - mean(x2)
ttst = t.test(
   x = x1,
   y = x2,
   alternative = "two.sided",
   mu = mean.diff,
   paired = FALSE,
   var.equal = FALSE,
   conf.level = 0.95
)
```

The result is *always* a t-value of zero and a p-value of 1, suggesting that the two vectors are identical. This happens regardless of the vectors, I simply chose x1 and x2 as examples.

What is wrong with my code that causes this please? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example, you're testing whether the difference in means is different from `mean.diff`; since you calculate `mean.diff` as the difference in means of `x1` and `x2` (`mean.diff = mean(x1) - mean(x2)`), the t statistic is exactly 0 and the corresponding p-value is maximal (i.e. equals 1). So we cannot reject the null hypothesis H0, where H0 corresponds to the difference in means being equal to `mean.diff`.

Comment: So to summarise in this case `mu` should be not used, so that it takes the default value of 0? Then `t.test` tests if the difference between the means of `x1` and `x2` is different itself to `mu = 0`? That makes sense, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @GMSL *"So to summarise in this case mu should be not used"* Well, it always depends on what you are testing. If you want to test whether two sample means are different `mu1 != mu2` you'd use a two-sided two-sample t-test of the form `t.test(x1, x2)`; if you want to test whether the difference in sample means is different from a pre-specified difference `mu1 - mu2 != mu` you'd use a two-sided two-sample t-test of the form `t.test(x1, x2, mu = mu)`.

Answer (score 1):

The result you are obtaining has nothing to do with the assignment: it is caused by the argument `mu = mean.diff`.

According to `?t.test`, mu is

> a number indicating the true value of the mean (or difference in means if you are performing a two sample test).

Since you set it to the actual value of the difference in means, the resulting t will always be equal to zero.